# Is there a .NET class that wraps WSACreateEvent and other WSA calls?

Tags: c#, winsock2

I'm converting some C++ code to C# and there are 5 functions that I need to 'translate':

- WSACreateEvent
- WSAWaitForMultipleEvents
- WSASetEvent
- WSAResetEvent
- WSAGetLastError

Is there a .NET class that wraps this functionality or do I need to make native calls?

Answer (score 0):

If the code uses Windows Sockets 2, i.e. other WSA functions, you can use P/Invoke to call these functions. If not, [ManualResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.manualresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provides equivalent functionality.